# MySQL DELETE JOIN over 3 tables doesn't work under specific circumstances

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 tables in MySQL and I'm processing the following DELETE-Statement:

```
DELETE c, b, e
FROM category c, block b, element e
WHERE
    c.category_id = 1 AND
    c.category_template_id = 1 AND
    b.block_category_id = c.category_id AND
    e.element_category_id = c.category_id
```

This DELETE-Statement works perfect, the data row in the table category with id = 1 will be deleted and also the corresponding data row(s) in the table block and in the table element.

But in the case there's no corresponding data in the table block and / or in the table element, the DELETE-Statement doesn't delete anything at all (even there is one data row with id = 1 in category).

How can I change the statement to cover this problem? I searched mysql-docs, google and stackoverflow for nearly 14 hour now. Please help me.

Thanks for answering!

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: I'm using InnoDB.

Comment: Your using AND, unless all condition met it won't delete so make sure you need last two conditions to be true every time even your category_template_id is 1

Comment: I was going to suggest using `ON DELETE CASCADE`, if that would make sense for this delete.

Comment: Use `JOIN` instead of merge all table in delete statement in `from`

Comment: If you are using the InnoDB then you can use foreign key relations to delete relation table data like ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: Also as @TimBiegeleisen suggested use `ON DELETE CASCADE` if yuo are using `InnoDB` so if you delete record from parent table, records of child table can be automatically deleted

Comment: Ok ... ON DELETE CASCADE ... I'll google it and try to change my statement. Thanks for answering - I'll tell you if I found the solution!

Comment: dont you thinks its better to separate the delete into 3 commands? like delete table1 where...; delete table2 where..., delete table3 where...;

Comment: @myyvee You would have to alter your table definitions.  `ON DELETE CASCADE` would make good sense if, for example, you are deleting from the other two tables because they refer to records in the first.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: They refer to records in the first, but I don't know (now) how to perform this ON DELETE CASCADE Statement, but I'm searching for it just at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `mysql JOIN` in your query like below,

```
DELETE c, b, e
FROM category c
LEFT JOIN block b ON c.category_id = b.block_category_id LEFT JOIN element e ON e.element_category_id = c.category_id
WHERE c.category_id = 1 AND c.category_template_id = 1;
```

May this will help you

Comment: You should add an explanation why `LEFT JOIN` solves the problem (No `b` to delete, when `c` or `e` does not exists with matching `id`), namely the difference of `LEFT JOIN` and `(INNER) JOIN`.

Comment: Welcome @myyvee :-)

Answer (score -1):

Change your table definitions for `block` and `element` using the following:

```
ALTER TABLE block
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_block_category
FOREIGN KEY (block_category_id)
REFERENCES category (category_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE

ALTER TABLE element
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_element_category
FOREIGN KEY (element_category_id)
REFERENCES category (category_id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Now when you do the following delete:

```
DELETE
FROM category
WHERE
    category_id = 1 AND
    category_template_id = 1;
```

in addition to removing the matching `category` records, all the records in the other two tables which refer to the deleted records in `category` will also be removed.

Note that there probably is a way to remedy your current delete join query.  If you were using MyISAM, this would be your only option.  But since you are using InnoDB, `ON DELETE CASCADE` might be a much more sane way to go here.